# evento na propriedade ou usar addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, propriedade

Uma coisa que eu sempre quis saber, se é padrão utilizar `addEventListener` ou a propriedade da tag `<body onload="">`. Alguns dizem que é o `addEventListener` e outros dizem que é pela propriedade. Alguém tem uma resposta OFICIAL?

Eu gostaria de saber também porque o `addEventListener` as vezes ativa o evento 4 vezes sem motivo nenhum. Ele me parece totalmente bugado e ainda nem funciona em Internet Explorer antigo. Pra que vou usar uma coisa dessas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar ambos. Ambos fazem o que se pede deles.

É verdade que o Internet Explorer tinha sérios bugs e não suportou, durante muito tempo, o `addEventListener`. Esses tempos são do passado.

**A regra que vejo entre programadores é** similar no JavaScript e CSS. Da mesma maneira que não é boa prática ter CSS *inline* também se deve **separar o JavaScript do HTML**. O método correto é usar `addEventListener`, ou seja JavaScript fora do HTML.

Errado, pois torna impossivel seguir o JavaScript dentro do HTML:

```
<div onclick="if(a == 20){ chamarMinhaFuncao(this, 203); }else{ a = 25; chamarOutraFuncao(this, null); return false}">Clique aqui!</div>
```

Certo, limpo e separado do HTML:

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('click', function(){ // ou div.onclick = function(){
    if (a == 20) {
        chamarMinhaFuncao(this, 203);
    } else {
        a = 25;
        chamarOutraFuncao(this, null);
        return false
    }
}
```